# Neo4J - Cypher example

Tags: nosql, neo4j

I got a bit of interest in graph databases, but I have some doubts. I did some superficial research (reading) which did not cleared things (I am familiar with graphs and graphs algorithms). Please excuse my laziness...but if you have time please give a shot to this question. How can the following SQL query be translated to Neo4J Cypher:

Give all customers which have orders where each order amount exceeds $100 and the number of products per order is grater than 3.

Can such scenario be modeled in Neo4J?

Comment: `Please excuse my laziness`. No.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized. Asking for a translation for a specific query does not help the community.

Comment: This is not about a specific query. At least not from my point of view, it is more about how this can be achieved if it can be achieved. About the laziness part...I am really busy at the moment but my brain is in turmoil caused by curiosity, I can't allocate time for this so I assumed that some one with experience related to Neo4J could answer it without much trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some 2.0 Cypher for a hypothetical model:

```
match c:Customer-[:ordered]->o:Order-[:contains]->p:Product
where o.total > 100.00
with c, o, count(p) as pcount
where pcount > 3
return distinct c;
```